# How to Make Instantiated Prefab Move According to its Rotation and Velocity in Unity2D

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I have a shooter game that I am working on that has a problem with the Instantiated bullets. The angle of the gun syncs with the angle of the bullet in the `Instantiate()` line of the code, and I even set the `Rigidbody2D` angle to the gun's rotational value, but when I do the line `rb.velocity = new Vector2(10f, 0);` it shoots in a straight line towards the right without taking into account its rotation in `transform.rotation` nor `rigidbody.rotation`. I have tried every which way to rotate the object, but I don't think this is the problem because my current code gets the bullet to have the correct rotational value according to the inspector, it just doesn't rotate the velocity of the `GameObject`. Here is my code that evaluates the angle of the gun:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PointAtMouse : MonoBehaviour
{
    Vector3 mouse_pos;
    Transform target; //Assign to the object you want to rotate
    Vector3 object_pos;
    float angle;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        target = gameObject.transform;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        mouse_pos = Input.mousePosition;
        mouse_pos.z = 5.23f; //The distance between the camera and object
        object_pos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(target.position);
        mouse_pos.x = mouse_pos.x - object_pos.x;
        mouse_pos.y = mouse_pos.y - object_pos.y;
        angle = Mathf.Atan2(mouse_pos.y, mouse_pos.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(new Vector3(0, 0, angle - 90));
    }
}
```

and here is my code that should instantiate the bullet:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ShootBullet : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject bulletPrefab;
    float reload;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(reload <= 0 && Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            GameObject bullet = Instantiate(bulletPrefab, gameObject.transform.position, gameObject.transform.rotation);
            Rigidbody2D rb = bullet.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(10, 0);
            reload = .1f;
        }

        if(reload > 0)
        {
            reload -= Time.deltaTime;
        }
    }
}
```

Keep in mind the `gameObject` in the `ShootBullet` class is attached to the gun, not the bullet, and that the Prefab has a `SpriteRenderer` attached to it that is functioning fine. Should I set the `Vector2` to sin and cos values according to the rotation? My thoughts on doing that would be that Unity already has some way of doing it anyway, but I've tried all sorts of things that have no effect.

EDIT:
I have managed to get the bullet to rotate somewhat (only from -45 to 45 degrees) with this line:

```
rb.velocity = new Vector2(Mathf.Sin(bullet.transform.rotation.z) * 10, Mathf.Cos(bullet.transform.rotation.z) * 10);
```

Does anyone know how I could fix this line so it spans all 360 degrees?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out with a little more research that the answer is this line:

```
rb.velocity = transform.up * 10f;
```

where `10f` is the speed.

Comment: Your answer is helpful, you can make it mark so that it can help more people